# When running a daemon, how do I execute a command from a given directory?

Tags: shell-script, directory, daemon, init-script, exec

My shell script knowledge is a little shaky, but I want to run a daemon (Ubuntu 14.04) defined in /etc/init.d/unicorn, like so

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        check_config
        check_app_root

        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" $NAME || true
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS; then
```

In a separate file, /etc/default/unicorn, I have the below variables defined:

```
APP_ROOT=/home/rails/myproject
...
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E $RAILS_ENV"
...
DAEMON="cd $APP_ROOT; $GEM_HOME/bin/bundle exec $GEM_PATH/bin/unicorn"
```

I added "cd $APP_ROOT" because that's the directory from where "$GEM_HOME/bin/bundle" must run.  However, when I go to start my service, I get the below error:

```
myuser@myproject:~$ sudo service unicorn restart
/home/rails/.gem/bin/bundle
 * Restarting Unicorn web server unicorn
start-stop-daemon: unable to stat //cd (No such file or directory)
```

Is there some other way I can store my options so that I can run my command from the desired directory?

Comment: You could use `sh -c '<commands>'` after `exec` (or `--exec`): since `exec` doesn't understand shell commands -- only a path (1'st argument) and a set of arguments for that executable (rest of arguments).

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading you right, but I changed "--exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS" to '--exec sh -c "$DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS"' and got the error "start-stop-daemon: unable to stat //cd (No such file or directory)" upon trying to start the service.

Comment: To get the idea try `<your-favorite-terminal> -e "sh -c 'echo hello; read'"` and a version without `sh -c`...

Comment: Shoot you're trying to tell me somethign and I'm totally missing it.  Are you sayhing put quotes around "sh"?  If so, I tried --exec "sh -c '$DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS'" and got teh error "start-stop-daemon: unable to stat //cd (No such file or directory)" upon trying to start my service.

Comment: I simply need to put somewhat more efforts to tell you exactly what you need to change. Ok, I'll try. \\ Try `--exec sh -c "$DAEMON $UNICORN_OPTS"` first. And put `echo "Execution of $DAEMON $UNICORN_OPTS..."` above the line, to know exactly what it's expanded into. \\ Anyway, it's ugly. Maybe you should better put the whole command with parameters into a separate file and give just that file to `--exec`?

Comment: Ok cool, I feel like we're getting somewhere.  The echo line prints out 'Execution of cd /home/rails/myproject; /home/rails/.gem/bin/bundle exec /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn -D -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production' .  Then the daemon exeuction line dies with "start-stop-daemon: unable to stat //cd (No such file or directory)"

Comment: Well, so you have the command correctly expanded, and `--exec` fails to hand it over to a shell and fails to simply treat it like `exec` does. I don't know what kind of thing `start-stop-daemon` does with it's arguments... probably homogenizes them somehow. But then I'd just put the whole command(s) into a script and just said `--exec /path/to/the-script.sh`. If that fails too, then I don't know what to think... :)

Comment: I don't fully get it ether. However `cd` is a shell built-in (it has to be), and if exec is not using a shell, it will be I assume execing it. To do that the file must first be stated, the file is `cd`, maybe the `//` is pretended to insure absolute paths (don't know why two `/`s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a few problem with what you are doing.

- `--exec` only takes one argument, however arguments can be passed at the end of `start-stop-daemon` following a `--`.
- The argument of `--exec` is also used as an identifier: `start-stop-daemon` checks to see if there is an instance running (this would make `/bin/sh`, a very bad candidate.

Therefore create a shell-script, that is expected to have one instance running per machine. Pass the absolute path to `--exec`. Pass any arguments needed by the script at the end after a `--`.

Comment: You are crediting me with more Unix knowledge than I actually posess.  What would be the contents of such a shell script?

Comment: @Dave The contents of your `DAEMON` variable, I guess. Together with the definitions of the path variables used there.